# Scrolling UITableView on show/hide keyboard iOS11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard

I'm using the following code to scroll UITableView and its footer on showing/hiding the keyboard. It was working well with me in iOS 10, but once I updated to iOS 11 the scrolling not work well.

code:

```
func registerNotificationObservers()
{      
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ArticleDetailsVC.keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(ArticleDetailsVC.keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func removeNotificationObservers()
{
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("keyboardWillShow")
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    {
        if self.commentsTableView.frame.origin.y == 0{
            print("keyboardWillShow ..")
            self.tableViewFooter.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height - 50
            self.commentsTableView.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height

        }


    }
}


@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("keyboardWillHide")

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    {
        if self.commentsTableView.frame.origin.y != 0{

            print("keyboardWillHide ..")
            self.tableViewFooter.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height + 50
            self.commentsTableView.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height   
        }  

    }
}
```

Hope to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After adding following lines (normally in `viewDidLoad()`), your tableView's behavior will be the same as iOS 10's:

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.commentsTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    }
```

Comment: I have tried your code and mine, the tableView will move up when keyboard showing on iOS 11. Remember to call your `registerNotificationObservers()` method and mine code in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: My code works well when the app just launch, but when I hide keyboard by `self.view.endEditing(true)` then try to show it again, the table not scroll

Answer (score 0):

As `UITableView` inherits `UIScrollView` , You use this `UIScrollViewDelegate` function below :

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) 
 {
        if scrollView == self.tableView
        {
            // show/hide Keyboard
        } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After putting the breakpoint under *if let keyboardSize* I saw that sometimes, for UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey keyboard height might be 0.0

Changing **UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey** to **UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey** helped me in this situation

So your code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("keyboardWillShow")
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    {
        if self.commentsTableView.frame.origin.y == 0{
            print("keyboardWillShow ..")
            self.tableViewFooter.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height - 50
            self.commentsTableView.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height

        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem too

As for the *keyboardWillHide* method, I've left it with **UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey** because there was no issues with it